# terraform modules from git

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, terraform

Sample below will download the terraform files from bitbucket **TAG** and deploy the aws resources.

```
module "S3-BUCKET" {
source      = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket-url:7999/project/s3-terraform-code.git?ref=tags/v1.0"
NAME        = "bucket-sample"
ENVIRONMENT = "prod"
}
```

**QUESTION:** can we also download the code from **BRANCH** instead of from bitbucket **TAG**?
Lets say **staging** is the name of the branch what can be the format to replace this line?

```
source      = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket-url:7999/project/s3-terraform-code.git?ref=tags/v1.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as explained in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#selecting-a-revision) you should be able to do the following to get `staging` branch:

```
module "S3-BUCKET" {
source      = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket-url:7999/project/s3-terraform-code.git?ref=staging"
NAME        = "bucket-sample"
ENVIRONMENT = "prod"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Based on the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#generic-git-repository), it appears setting the `ref` attribute directly to the branch name should work:

```
source      = "git::ssh://git@bitbucket-url:7999/project/s3-terraform-code.git?ref=master"
```

Furthermore, if this is a public bitbucket repository, you can use an unprefixed source such as:

```
source      = "bitbucket.org/project-name/s3-terraform-code.git?ref=master"
```